# How to set short tag(<?) in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using WAMPP for PHP server and in programming short tag use create a problem. I knew that it possible by change something in php.ini file but I don't know the setting for that please help me for that.

example:

```
<? echo "hi"; ?> //error....want to allow this also.
<?php echo "hi"; ?> //ok
```

---

I found this in PHP config setting file but what changes require I don't know...

```
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

Comment: With `shot_open_tag` you can also write `<?= "hi" ?>` instead of `<? echo "hi" ?>`.

Comment: Imo it is better to get used to normal open tags...

Comment: @FelixKling: Why do you think is it better to get used to normal open tags?

Comment: @ONOZ because they are turned off in almost any environment by default. Many hosters don't even allow to change that.

Answer (score 20):

In your php.ini change the `short_open_tag = Off` if it's there to this:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 11):

Click on your wamp icon then "PHP". Then click on "PHP Settings". There should be an option for "short open tag" which you should enable by clicking on it, it should show a check mark. Your wamp server will automatically restart in a few seconds and then short open tag will be enabled.

For non-wamp you need to go to your php.ini file and uncomment `short_open_tag = On`

Answer (score 5):

set `short_open_tag = 1` in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/short_open_tag = Off/short_open_tag = On/g' /etc/php.ini
grep -n short_open_tag php.ini
```

first line does inlien replace of php.ini to turn on short tags
second makes sure its there

Comment: Most php.ini files are in a sub folder with the php version. For example `/etc/php/5.6/php.ini`

Answer (score 1):

Sometime setting `short_open_tag = On` on your php.ini will not work because in some cases, `short_open_tag` define more than one. So find all `short_open_tag` and set `On` or `1`.

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Answer (score 0):

Wamp 2.5 contains two versions of php.ini. If you're running php inside Apache (as I guess you are) you need to change the one in \bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin.

Comment: For Wamp's current version, its wiser to edit the settings here \bin\php\php7.4.26\phpForApache.ini