# How can I correct this Syntax error in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why am I getting this Syntax error on line 3 in config.php?  `syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE) in` 
This is my config.php file:

```
<?
$host='localhost'; 
$username="xxxxxxx"; 
$dbname="xxxxxxx"; 
$password="xxxxxxx";

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: That code snippet above does not produce any error.

Comment: Yes but in my hosting it shows error

Comment: should be  <?php  ......

Comment: How is this possible

Comment: Oh wait I am checking with <?php

Comment: Short tags would not produce any kind of error, it would just output as HTML

Comment: Still getting this error PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$username' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Can you post the whole error string= @NalinNishant

Comment: Maybe for some reason, check if there are any weird characters in the file. Re-type the quotes just in case..

Comment: From the code you have here, there's no reason for the error; Do you call for `$username` anywhere else?

Comment: Wait I am sending you full screenshot as a proof

Comment: Usually this error is triggered because you are missing a ";" (semi-colon) or you have a random character in you code in the line above... Check wherever you are calling for `$username`

Comment: K I am checking wait.... And this is not duplicate question :-(

Comment: No I am not calling anywhere username with missing ; ..... @samuel . This is config.php file through which I connect with my database..... Wait I am showing you full screenshot

Comment: https://ibb.co/mZV8Rv -> screenshot 1.  https://ibb.co/k6EreF ->screenshot 2.               https://ibb.co/fLWnKF ->screenshot 3.

Comment: So you are actually getting a `500 Internal Error`. So something may be wrong with your request and it is not working on your server. Now I am not sure exactly why it's triggering the error. Do you have any more information?

Comment: 500 comes from the corrupted PHP @Samuel. His error.log shows that. Nalin Nishant rewrite the file in a new document, don't copy paste anything. Write it manually from the beginning.

Comment: I would not mark this as a duplicate to the given list since none of the solutions there can be applied to this one.

Answer (score -1):

This is due to php short opening tags are not enabled. You should either enable it or use full tags instead.

Use `<?php` instead of just `<?`

OR

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645898/how-to-set-short-tag-in-php) thread to enable short tags.

Comment: This would not cause the error he is getting. Short tag would have nothing to do with the `$username` mate; if any variable it would be `$host`

Comment: Got you. Thanks!